# How to load columns from text file with numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a text file with rows and each row has 3 floats separeted with space. I am only interested to load the 2nd and the 3rd column. I typed:

```
b=np.loadtxt('file.txt',delimiter=(' '),usecols=(1,2))
```

but i am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Comment: I think the error is somewhere else in your code, because here it seems to work with the output `array([[ 2.2,  3.3], [ 5.5,  6.6], [ 8.8,  9.9]])`.

Comment: what version of numpy do you have?

Comment: numpy version : 1.6.1

Comment: I also have numpy 1.6 and the above code works fine